# Is it possible to add dummy devices in Microsoft Intune (Endpoint Manager)?

Tags: intune, microsoft-graph-intune, microsoft-graph-api

We are working on a feature that makes use of MS Intune Graph API.

To properly support pagination, we need more than 100 devices in Intune. However, we don't have so many devices right now. Is it possible to populate 100 dummy devices in Endpoint Manager (MS Intune)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why using `$top` parameter is not an option in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yeah, I'm using $top and @odata.nextLink but I expect to test with a bunch of devices in all categories, which I don't have right now. If there is no other go, then I'll manage with this :)